# Signing in to Google Sheets from Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-oauth, powerquery

I can use the Power Query tool to import data from Google Sheets easily, if the sheet is publicly available via a link. I just choose "Data from Web" and use the Google Sheets link like this:
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sOMe-un1n7eLLig_ible-kEy/export&format=xlsx`

As authentication option I choose anonymous. The "Standard" method with my google username and password always results in "wrong credentials". What is the way here to get the authentication working?

*Update:* **What I have found out so far**

- I will have to use OAuth2.0.
- There is a [Google Sheets (beta)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/googlesheets) connector in the Microsoft documentation, but I cannot find the connector in my Power Query Editor. It only appears in Power BI Desktop.
- “[Accessing API with Oauth2 using M language in Power BI](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/accessing-api-oauth2-using-m-language-power-bi-diogenes-santos)” is very detailed description on how to use OAuth2.0 in *Power Query M*, but no information on the Google API
- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) gives some hints to the Google OAuth2.0 API.

**Update 2022-04-19**

- There is a [step-by-step guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/samples/github/readme) on how to use Power Query to access Git-Hub with OAuth2.0. It uses a Power BI URL as a redirect URL.
- Google offers some [sample implementations](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows) of the OAuth2.0 process in C#.

My current problem is, that apparently Google has removed the option to allow any other **redirect-URI** than localhost in the client-id config.

Comment: I have not used Power Query recently so I'm not sure what you mean by `"Standard" method with my google username and password` but I can tell that Google uses OAuth 2 for managing user authentication to Google Sheets and all other web apps, not a "basic authentication" (username and password). Look for how to use a REST API as data source and more specifically how to use the  Google Sheets API as a data source.

Comment: This is the standard web link you need to use in Power Query --> **`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{ID}/export?format=xlsx&id={ID}","{ID}`** where the **`{ID}`** needs to be replaced with `sOMe-un1n7eLLig_ible-kEy`